# Binary-vectorize pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In a fictional patients dataset one might encounter the following table:

```py
pd.DataFrame({
    "Patients": ["Luke", "Nigel", "Sarah"],
    "Disease": ["Cooties", "Dragon Pox", "Greycale & Cooties"]
})
```

Which renders the following dataset:

[image: Fictional diseases]

Now, assuming that the rows with multiple illnesses use the same pattern (separation with a character, in this context a `&`) and that there exists a complete list `diseases` of the illnesses, I've yet to find a simple solution to applying to these situations [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) one-hot encoder to obtain a binary vector for each patient.

How can I obtain, in the simplest possible manner, the following binary vectorization from the initial DataFrame?

```py
pd.DataFrame({
    "Patients": ["Luke", "Nigel", "Sarah"],
    "Cooties":[1, 0, 1],
    "Dragon Pox":[0, 1, 0],
    "Greyscale":[0, 0, 1]
})
```

[image: Desired result]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Series.str.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html#pandas-series-str-get-dummies) with right separator,

```
df.set_index('Patients')['Disease'].str.get_dummies(' & ').reset_index()

    Patients    Cooties Dragon Pox  Greycale
0   Luke        1       0           0
1   Nigel       0       1           0
2   Sarah       1       0           1
```

Comment: Great answer, didnt know about `str.get_dummies` +1 for better answer

Comment: What is the importance of `' & '` arg in `get_dummies`? Is this arg related to this question context only?

Answer (score 2):

We can unnest your string to rows using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51752361/9081267) function.

After that we use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) with `aggfunc=len`:

```
df = explode_str(df, 'Disease', ' & ')

print(df)
  Patients     Disease
0     Luke     Cooties
1    Nigel  Dragon Pox
2    Sarah    Greycale
2    Sarah     Cooties
```

---

```
df.pivot_table(index='Patients', columns='Disease', aggfunc=len)\
  .fillna(0).reset_index()

Disease Patients  Cooties  Dragon Pox  Greycale
0           Luke      1.0         0.0       0.0
1          Nigel      0.0         1.0       0.0
2          Sarah      1.0         0.0       1.0
```

---

Function used from linked answer:

```
def explode_str(df, col, sep):
    s = df[col]
    i = np.arange(len(s)).repeat(s.str.count(sep) + 1)
    return df.iloc[i].assign(**{col: sep.join(s).split(sep)})
```

Comment: `get_dummies` is a better choice than `pivot_table` here.

Comment: get_dummies wont give expected output as OP is asking. You will get 4 rows, at least to my knowledge, but feel free to post your own answer

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

You could check the occurrence of `disease` in `df['Disease']` in a loop:

```
>>> diseases = ['Cooties', 'Dragon Pox', 'Greycale']
>>> for disease in diseases:
>>>     df[disease] = pd.Series(val == disease for val in df['Disease'].values).astype(int)
```

## Option 2

Alternatively, you could use `.get_dummies`, after you split the strings in `df['Disease']` by `'& '`.

```
>>> sub_df = df['Disease'].str.split('& ', expand=True)
>>> dummies = pd.get_dummies(sub_df)
>>> dummies

#    0_Cooties  0_Dragon Pox  0_Greycale   1_Cooties
# 0          1             0            0          0
# 1          0             1            0          0
# 2          0             0            1          1

# Let's rename the columns by taking only the text after the '_'
>>> _, dummies.columns = zip(*dummies.columns.str.split('_'))
>>> dummies.groupby(dummies.columns, axis=1).sum()

#      Cooties  Dragon Pox   Greycale 
#   0        1           0          0
#   1        0           1          0
#   2        1           0          1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to a similar problem but in slightly a different context.

My dataframe is like this.

```
project    lib
p1          l1
p1          l2
p2          l3
p3          l2
```

My intended output is like this:

```
project    l1   l2   l3
p1          1    1    0
p2          0    0    1
p3          0    1    0
```

If I use `get_dummies`, my output is like this:

```
  project  l1  l2  l3
0      p1   1   0   0
1      p1   0   1   0
2      p3   0   0   1
3      p2   0   1   0
```

For me, `pivot_table` gave the intended output.

Here is a minimal example:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({
        'project': ['p1', 'p1', 'p3', 'p2'],
        'lib': ['l1', 'l2', 'l3', 'l2']
    })
df_dummy = df_test.pivot_table(index="project", columns="lib", aggfunc=lambda x: 1, fill_value=0)
print(df_dummy)
```